# what is 'android:' in layout.xml file?

Tags: android

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, the `application` tag has an attribute of 'android:icon'.

What does the 'android:' part mean?

As in:

```
<application>
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
</application>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `android` in `android:icon` is the namespace for the framework. It indicates that the attribute is from the Android framework and not a custom attribute for example.

Comment: Please do not make edits, if they do not add or fix anything in/to the question. You only took out the `Blockquote`, but did not fix any formatting, or code (the xml itself was wrong).

Comment: @zyboxinternational Did you see the question before I made the edit? You couldn't understand anything.

Comment: Yes, and still the question cannot be understood. I have submitted a suggested edit, and it'll probably be approved. (edit: it just got approved)

Comment: @zyboxinternational your edit did make the question more clear but Ahmad's fixed quite a bit by removing the blockquote and adding the xml snippet into code blocks

Comment: @codeMagic True, though for some reason SO didn't let me see the edit until after I submitted my suggested edit, so it got cancelled until I resubmitted it. Weird.